# Fixed height div + strechy height div = 100% screen height. Is it possible?

Tags: html, css

I have this template in my mind

[image]

And i dont know how i can implement second "stretchy div". It must fill with his height all remaining space on the screen (not bigger, because I don`t want to see y-scroll). Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`viewport units` and `calc` make this simpler.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.one {
  height: 50px; /* demo height */
  background: red;
}
.two {
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

**EDIT: Flexbox version**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.one {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.two {
  background: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

Comment: perhaps `100%` might be better, just to give better browser coverage. This is the answer though.

Comment: 100%  of what though...can't be the body because the body might exceed viewport height.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkzqkfgs/). Hope it helps!

HTML -

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
#wrapper {
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#first {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#F5DEB3;
}
#second {
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:300px;
    background-color:#9ACD32;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use resize event of javascript window object.Listen for this event then we have to update our visual elements(div..etc) manually.

Comment: Could you share an example/code snippet of how to do this, not just mention vaguely how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want a "stretchy" second div, which my example shows.

```
.firstDiv {
    height: 400px;
}

.secondDiv {
    height: 100%;
}
```

The second div must have content in it or it will not be seen, however the height of it will be determinant on what is inside the div, so it will stretch as you need.

Comment: You've interpreted _stretchy_ incorrectly, this does not solve the OPs problem. If a height is not set on the parent element of `.secondDiv`, `.secondDiv` will behave as a regular DIV with no class applied to it. If a height is set on the parent element `.secondDiv` would not properly stretch to fill the remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

```
.div1{
height:400px;
z-index:1;
}

.div2{
height:100%;
position:relative;
top:-400px;
z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: Please explain **with words** what this means.